# Picklist selected value auto populate to textbox in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

We have PE, and we need to create a VF page. In that page we have created a picklist which has 5 values. When we select a value from the picklist a text box next to that picklist should automatically populate a message similar to that value selected.
ie., if our picklist has red, blue, green, when we select "red" then the textbox should  populate this message "this is red" likewise. How we can to this?  But for PE there is no Apex class how can we achieve this.

Comment: Is your page visualforce or standard layout?

Comment: why is that every time you post a question we see no efforts from you, have you worked on something to start with.As a gentel request putin your maximum efforts cook up some basic code, all the members would appriciate your efforts and pour in answers. More efforts gives you better understanding of the subject and will benefit you in a longer run.

Comment: Also you don't appear to have voted up or accepted any of the answers to questions you've raised in the past. If they have been useful to you, acknowledge this so that other people with the same problem can take advantage of the guidance. If you have solved the problem another way, share your work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use jQuery / javascript to populate the field. You could do something like this:

```
//load the jQuery library
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$(document).ready(function(){
    //I have assumed the id of the picklist field is pickField and text box is inputTextBox
    j$("[id*=pickField]").change(function(){
         var pickListValue = j$(this).val();
         j$("[id*=inputTextBox]").val('this is '+ pickListValue);
    });
});
</script>
```